# Rails not saving nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, fields-for

I have the tables Task and Item. I have a form for Item where I record all the possible items that my Tasks may have, which is working fine. Then I have the form for Task where all the Items are displayed alongside a field to put a cost value for each item. This will result in a join between Task and Item: TaskItem (this table contains task_id, item_id and cost).

When I submit the form, it's saving the Task but not the TaskItems associated. I don't see what I'm missing as I searched a lot for this problem and nothing seems to work. Please, see the code below.

Model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :task_items
    has_many :items, :through => :task_items

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_items, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :task_items
    has_many :tasks, :through => :task_items
end

class TaskItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :item

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @items = Item.all

    @task = Task.new
    @task.task_items.build
end

def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.save
    redirect_to action: "index"
end

private def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:id, :title, task_items_attributes: [:id, :item_id, :cost])
end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for :task, url:tasks_path do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:title, {:class => 'form-control'}) %><br>
</p>

<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <% @task_items = TaskItem.new %>
    <%= f.fields_for :task_items do |ti| %>
        <%= ti.label item.description %>
        <%= ti.text_field :cost %>
        <%= ti.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<p>
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %>
</p>
```

Comment: What is the log output when you try to save a `TaskItem`?

Comment: Using  render plain: params[:task].inspect  I got this: <ActionController::Parameters {"title"=>"Teste 1", "task_items"=>{"item_id"=>"4", "cost"=>"55"}} permitted: false>

Comment: "task"=>{"title"=>"Teste565656", "task_items"=>{"item_id"=>"4", "cost"=>"55"}}, "commit"=>"Save Contato"}
Unpermitted parameter: task_items
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (21.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("title", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Teste565656"], ["created_at", 2017-03-09 19:31:41 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-09 19:31:41 UTC]]
   (122.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/

Comment: You have an error in your `task_params` error: it should state :cost instead of :valor according with the code present in your view

Comment: sorry, task_params fixed but it wasn't the cause of the problem. somehow task_items_attributes are not being understandood on saving my task.

Comment: According with your params log, you are not receiving a *task_items_attributes* hash, so it won't create from the task the inner TaskItem's objects

Comment: How could I make it receive a task_item_attributes? I thought it was done automatically by the nested_attributes

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check if it works for you now

Comment: Thanks for the patience but unfortunately is still not working. I changed the fields_for and controller as you mentioned but still got unpermitted parameter: task_items.

Comment: I did another update to show the all the code of my controller and view

Comment: thank you very much, it worked doing all the changes you suggest...

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `inverse_of` option to the `has_many` method in class Task:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :task_items, inverse_of: :task
  has_many :items, through: :task_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_items, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

This is due to the when creating a new TaskItem instance, it requires that the Task instance already exists in database to be able to grab the `id` fo the Task instance. Using this option, it skips the validation.

You can read this [post](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations) about `inverse_of` option and its use cases.

`fields_for` has an option to specify the object which is going to store the information. This combined with building each of the TaskItem from the `has_many` collection should ensure that all the relationship are set correctly.

View Code:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field(:title, {:class => 'form-control'}) %><br>
  </p>

  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <% task_item = @task.task_items.build %>
    <%= f.fields_for :task_items, task_item do |ti| %>
      <%= ti.label item.description %>
      <%= ti.text_field :cost %>
      <%= ti.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit({:class => 'btn btn-primary'}) %>
  </p>  
<% end %>
```

Controller Code:

```
def index
end

def new
  @items = Item.all
  @task = Task.new
end

def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @task.save
  redirect_to action: "index"
end

private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:id, :title, task_items_attributes: [:id, :item_id, :cost])
end
```

Comment: It still says "Unpermitted parameter: task_items" in my log and the task_items are not created. Shoul I use inverse_of anywhere else? Am I using the _attributes correctly? Many thanks